# How to Bind the "Children" property of a "GeometryGroup" element in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to bind the `Children` property of a `GeometryGroup` element in XAML as below, But the expected geometry is not appearing on the Window.

The code in **xaml**:

```
<GeometryGroup Children="{Binding ChildElements}"/>
```

The code behind:

```
InitializeComponent();
ChildElements.Add(Geometry.Parse("//some geometry"));
```

The `ChildElements` is a `GeometryCollection` that is bound to the `Children` property of the `GeometryGroup`.

Comment: You don't seem do be setting a DataContext that could serve as source object of the binding. Try to add `DataContext = this;` after `ChildElements.Add(...);`.

Comment: Perfect catch! Thank you very much!